# Is there anyway to make socket.io-stream work as a browserify module?

Tags: socket.io, browserify

In the [github page](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream) it says that you can build browserify client script with browserify, so you can include it in your html like this:

```
<script src="socket.io-stream.js" ></script>
```

which I don't want to do. For other reasons, we need to have this component via require inside a main script which will be "browserified" as a big bundle.js, so i need to have it like this in a file called main.js :

```
var ss = require("socket.io-stream");
//... do wathever you want with ss.
```

And at the end, I will compile the file with browserify:

```
$browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Browserify runs great, but as soon as I try to use it, it throws me an error in browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './_stream_duplex'
```

I have tried by adding manually the module with require flag without success. like:

```
$browserify main.js -r socket.io-stream -o bundle.js
```

Any help on this ?